# How to fix error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on a scraping project using selenium in python, but I am running into an error when I try to print text that I get from an XPath element. The error says:

*print(AdditionalCerts.text)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'*

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/nzalle/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://directory.bcsp.org/")
count = int(input("Number of Pages to Scrape: "))

body = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body")
profile_count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@align='right']/a")

while len(profile_count) < count:    # Get links up to "count"
    body.send_keys(Keys.END)
    sleep(1)
    profile_count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@align='right']/a")

for link in profile_count:   # Calling up links
    temp = link.get_attribute('href')   # temp for
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")    # open new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])   # focus new tab
    driver.get(temp)

    # Scraping Code

    try:
        Name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[2]/div')

        IssuedBy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[2]')

        CertificationNumber = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[2]')

        CertfiedSince = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div[2]')

        RecertificationCycle = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div[2]')

        Expires = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/div[2]')

        AccreditedBy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/div[2]/a')

        AdditionalCerts = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[8]/div[1]/a/div/div')

    except NoSuchElementException:
        Name = "N/A"

        IssuedBy = "N/A"

        CertificationNumber = "N/A"

        CertfiedSince = "N/A"

        RecertificationCycle = "N/A"

        Expires = "N/A"

        AccreditedBy = "N/A"

        AdditionalCerts = "N/A"

    print(Name.text + " ; " + IssuedBy.text + " : " + CertificationNumber.text + " : " + CertfiedSince.text + " : " + RecertificationCycle + " : " + Expires.text + " : " + AccreditedBy.text + " : " + AdditionalCerts.text)

    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.close()
```

Please let me know how to view the text from my Name, IssuedBy, CertificationNumber, ext. Thank You :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in Python don't have a value `.text` you need to move these into the try.

```py
Name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(...).text
```

```py
print(Name + " ; " + ...)
```